# node.js heroku Ghost is unable to start due to missing dependencies: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, heroku, ghost

I've been working at this for a few hours, and no luck. I just went and downloaded `Ghost 0.7.0` onto my local machine and, out of the box, `npm start` worked perfectly. I'm running into an error when I attempt to install my first package. The package I'm installing is [ghost-s3-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ghost-s3-storage). However, all packages are returning similar errors when deploying to heroku.

Here are my steps...

```
$ npm start
    -> works
$ npm install --save ghost-s3-storage
$ npm start
    -> still works
```

So now my `package.json` contains accurate dependencies, so Heroku should deploy correctly, but it doesn't. It appears to be caused by three commands that Heroku runs (according to their [guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys#start-with-a-blank-slate)). And when I run the commands locally, I can replicate the error.

```
 $ rm -rf node_modules
 $ npm install --quiet --production
 $ npm start
   -> ERROR: Ghost is unable to start due to missing dependencies:
    Cannot find module 'ghost-s3-storage'
```

At this point, my `package.json` looks correct.

```
package.json
  "dependencies": {
    ...,
    "ghost-s3-storage": "^0.2.2",
    ...,
  }
```

However, `ghost-s3-storage` is missing from `node_modules`.

```
$ npm ls
   -> UNMET DEPENDENCY ghost-s3-storage@^0.2.2
   -> npm ERR! missing: ghost-s3-storage@^0.2.2, required by ghost@0.7.0
```

So I'm stumped. Either Heroku is being stupid, or node.js, or me. Please help.

Comment: Were you able to solve it? Having the same issue.

Comment: I was not. Contacted my friend and also Heroku

Comment: I got it working for me with npm shrinkwrap

Comment: if you are setting up a ghost instance on heroku check out this:
https://github.com/cobyism/ghost-on-heroku
It also has a fully working config.js

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue and I solved it by using `npm shrinkwrap`.

`npm shrinkwrap` locks down the package dependencies (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap)

Also see this recommendation:
https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/faq#should-i-check-my-node-modules-folder-into-git

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue and can report that running `npm shrinkwrap`, committing and deploying to Heroku solves the issue.